# How am I getting a "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" exception without ever calling recycle in code?

Tags: android

My ImageView is defined in the Activity layout and there's no ListView or GridView, so there's no automatic view recycling here. Whenever the Activity loads I get a crash with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" in logcat.
Here's the style for my ImageView. As you can see there's nothing special here. The only thing notable about the image is that it's pretty large (full screen size for a Nexus 10). I know that this view is the culprit since commenting it out resolves the error.

```
<style name="tabletbackground">
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/loading_background</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">background image</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
</style>
```

Nowhere in the code for this Activity is any call to recycle bitmaps made. Any idea what's going on here?

Here's some of the layout for the curious.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    style="@style/news_act_root" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/tabletbackground"
        android:id="@+id/tabletbackground" />

    <!-- redacted -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited. My original guess that it was caused by an alias would be misleading and confusing to anyone reading this.)

Well it looks like I stumbled on a solution.

I referenced the same drawable in a previously displayed Activity and I did recycle it there. This shouldn't cause the error, right? Well it does.

So don't expect the layout inflater to give you a new drawable. It may give you one it inflated previously if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is Scaling! The scaling part, returns a new image.
But when no scaling is needed, it returns the old instance again.
System recycles the old image, so the new image will recycle too! and you get "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps"
Remove the "scaleType" attribute and test again.